# How can i manipulate MySQL Datetime with php, (adding hours and converting to timezone)?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

In ma DB i have a table with rows of five columns:
1. start-time
2. end-time
3. planned-start-time
4. planned-duration
5. timezone

Now i want to actually return start and end time based on this logic:

**For established events:**

- if start-time **"not"** '0000-00-00 00:00:00', then use start-time as -> **start**
- if end-time **"not"**'0000-00-00 00:00:00', then use end-time as -> **end**

**For planned Events:**

- if start-time **"is"** '0000-00-00 00:00:00', then use planned-start-time as **start**
- if end-time **"is"** '0000-00-00 00:00:00', then use planned-start-time + duration (which are minutes::  expl: 200min.) as **end**

Now i have this json with my Timezone like so:

```
   { 
      dstOffset: 0
      rawOffset: 3600
      timeZoneId: "Europe/Zurich"
      timeZoneName:"Central European Standard Time"
    }
```

Now here i would like to convert the time which i get from above method, to this time zone and then output it like this: '2017-03-01 00:00:00'

How is the Best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to convert the unix time stamp to a mysql time stamp.

```
$timeToAdd = 200; // Number of seconds
$timeToAdd = 60 * 60; // 1 hours (3600 seconds)

//using one of the above $timeToAdd you can calculate it using the following
$mysql_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $timeToAdd);
```

**$mysql_time** now contains a the timestamp in mysql format

Ex: 2017-03-19 09:22:06